# Vertica/SQL: Getting rows immediately proceeding events

Tags: sql, vertica

Consider a simple query

```
select from tbl where status=MELTDOWN
```

I would like to now create a table that in addition to including these rows, also includes the previous p rows and the subsequent n rows, so that I can get a sense as to what happens in the surrounding time of these MELTDOWNs. Any hints?

Comment: Add timestamp/datetime column to do time analysis

Comment: It would certainly help if we new what the data looked like.

Comment: You would need to order by some field and then use lag and lead to get the values immediately before and after the event

Comment: Assume table is sorted by time epochs in nanos (from 1970), integer valued. The timestamps are not unique (multiple status updates can happen at the same time)

Comment: @bigO6377 If a MeltDown and a Hiccup happen at the same epoch, did the Hiccup occur before or after the Meltdown?  *(For the purposes of Preceding P row and Subsequent N rows)*

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, table is sorted by unique row-ids (which also happens to be in chronological time order)

Comment: Please share sample data & desired output. Generally speaking... Vertica's Event Based Analytic Functions (for example CONDIZIONALI_TRUE_EVENT()) deserve a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions by getting the seqnum of the meltdown rows.  I prefer to do this with `lag()/lead() ignore nulls`, but Vertical doesn't support that.  I think this is the equivalent with `first_value()/last_value()`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from tbl
     ),
     tt as (
      select t.*,
             last_value(case when status = 'meltdown' then seqnum end ignore nulls) over (order by seqnum rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as prev_meltdown_seqnum,
             first_value(case when status = 'meltdown' then seqnum end ignore nulls) over (order by seqnum rows between current row and unbounded following) as prev_meltdown_seqnum,
      from t
     )
select tt.*
from tt
where seqnum between prev_melt_seqnum and prev_melt_seqnum + 7 or
      seqnum between next_melt_seqnum -5 and next_melt_seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  grouped AS
(
  SELECT
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN status = 'Meltdown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    OVER (
      ORDER BY timeStamp
    )
      AS GroupID,
    tbl.*
  FROM
    tbl
),
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY timeStamp ASC )   AS incPos,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY timeStamp DESC)   AS decPos,
    MAX(GroupID) OVER ()                                               AS LastGroup
    grouped.*
  FROM
    grouped
)
SELECT
  sorted.*
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
     (incPos <= 8 AND GroupID  > 0        )   -- Meltdown and the 7 events following it
  OR (decPos <= 6 AND GroupID <> LastGroup)   --          and the 6 events preceding a Meltdown
ORDER BY
  timeStamp
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  For instance, I think it will select the first 8 and last 6 rows in the table.  I'm not going to answer (at least not any time soon), because you are on the right track.  You just need two separate groups, one for the befores and one for the afters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Ugly but reliable way to ensure first 8 rows only treated as "FollowingMeltdown" if first row is a Meltdown, and last 6 rows only treated as "PrecedingMeltdown" if final row is a MeltDown.